# Mounting Shared folders inside Docker machine on Windows

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, mount, docker

I have installed latest Docker Toolbox 1.11.2 on Windows 10. When I run `$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox default` - virtualbox creates image, everything is fine. Shared folders are configured by default:

[image]

When I connect to image using `$ docker-machine ssh` - shared folder is not mounted. And even if I try to mount it manually, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /c/Users && sudo mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` c/Users /c/Users
mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Invalid argument
mount: mounting c/Users on /c/Users failed: Protocol error
```

Comment: Usually, starting the docker `Quickstart Terminal` or `Kitematic` creates the `default` VM automatically. I'm not sure what you might miss by doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Virtual Guest Additions** on your virtual machine, by selecting *Insert Guest Additions CD Image* from the *Devices* menu.